# www-data user cannot access a Virtualbox shared folder through Docker container

Tags: docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu server VM running on a Windows 10 host, where a folder on an external hard drive is passed through to the VM at the mountpoint /NextCloudStorage. I can access this folder from my normal user, and from root, by adding my normal user to the vboxsf user group.

My Docker Compose file includes this to pass through the /NextCloudStorage to the container:

```
volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - .:/code
      - /NextCloudStorage:/NextCloudStorage
```

When using `docker exec -it nextcloud-app-1 bash`, I can interact with the shared folder live using commands such as `cd /NextCloudStorage`, `mkdir test1`, etc.

My problem is that the application running in the container cannot access this folder, because it runs as `www-data`. `ls` commands list the folder as empty, and when trying to create an item in the folder I get the error `"permission denied"`.

Does anyone know how to give the `www-data` user access to this shared folder?

Sorry for the long post but I had to spiel it out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to add the `www-data` user to the `vboxsf` group

To achieve this we need to figure out the group id. `In the virtual machine run`

```
cat /etc/group
```

You will see something like this

[image]

---

`Then in your container`, if this group doesnt exist create it

In this case the `gid` we need to use is 115

```
groupadd --gid 115 vboxsf
```

Next add this group to your `www-data user`

```
usermod -aG vboxsf www-data
```

---

**Update**:
Try to run the following command as root in the container

```
chmod -R 777 /NextCloudStorage
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that doesn't work - when running `usermod -aG vboxsf:x:997 www-data` I get the error "`group 'vboxsf:x:997' does not exist`".

Comment: Try only the id, meaning 997

Comment: There is the possibility that we need to create the group. I will update the answer

Comment: @TarasZagajewski Updated answer, in case group does not exist. Feel free to check again

Comment: unfortunately still nothing. The commands went through fine, and my `/etc/group` file within the container now shows `vboxsf:x:997:www-data`, but I still cannot list the directory with `ls`, or use `mkdir` as the `www-data` user without getting `permission denied`.

Comment: That's unfortunate, do you mind running ls -ld /NextCloudStorage . And post the results ?

Comment: Yep! As `www-data` within the container I get `2621441 /NextCloudStorage/`. Thanks so much for persisting!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I meant to ask for the owner and permissions of this directory if possible

Comment: `ls -l /NextCloudStorage/` returns `total 0`, I'm relitavely new to Linux, are you able to provide a command to run?

Comment: Yep, run: ls -ld /NextCloudStorage

Comment: Awesome, as `root` in the container, I get `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 05:06 /NextCloudStorage`

Comment: Added another approach @TarasZagajewski , give it a go

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment this but thank you very much this worked! I thought I discovered and run a similar command in my own research but apparently not!

Comment: I just used `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data`